# How to add data from the result-set obtained from MySQL query to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a list of dictionaries from the result-set obtained by executing MySQL query.

Following is the result-set (as `rows` in the form of a list) obtained from the result of executing MySQL query-

```
ip                ver     software  status          count
198.168.1.1       1.1     A         fail            5
198.168.1.1       1.1     A         pass            10
198.168.1.1       1.1     B         fail            15
198.168.1.1       1.1     B         pass            20
198.168.1.2       1.1     A         pass            25
```

This is what i tried-

```
    data_dict = {}
    data_list = []
    for row in rows:
       data_dict['ip'] = row[0]
       data_dict['version'] = row[1]
       data_dict['software'] = row[2]
       data_dict['pass'] = 0  # may be a case that software never passed. Hence default set to 0
       data_dict['fail'] = 0  # may be a case that software never failed. Hence default set to 0
       if row[3] == 'pass':
       data_dict['pass'] = row[4]
       if row[3] == 'fail':
       data_dict['fail'] = row[4]
       data_list.append(data_dict)
       data_dict = {}

    for item in data_list:
       print(item)
```

Actual results are -

```
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'A', 'pass': 0, 'fail': 5}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'A', 'pass': 10, 'fail': 0}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'B', 'pass': 0, 'fail': 15}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'B', 'pass': 20, 'fail': 0}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.2', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'A', 'pass': 25, 'fail': 0}
```

Expected results -

```
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'A', 'pass': 10, 'fail': 5}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.1', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'B', 'pass': 20, 'fail': 15}
   {'ip': '198.168.1.2', 'version': '1.1', 'software': 'A', 'pass': 25, 'fail': 0}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full solution:

```
rows = [
    ('198.168.1.1', '1.1', 'A', 'fail', 5),
    ('198.168.1.1', '1.1', 'A', 'pass', 10),
    ('198.168.1.1', '1.1', 'B', 'fail', 15),
    ('198.168.1.1', '1.1', 'B', 'pass', 20),
    ('198.168.1.2', '1.1', 'A', 'pass', 25),
]

data = {}

for row in rows:
    key = (row[0], row[1], row[2])
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = {
            'ip': row[0],
            'version': row[1],
            'software': row[2],
            'pass': 0,
            'fail': 0,
        }
    if row[3] == 'pass':
        data[key]['pass'] = row[4]
    else:
        data[key]['fail'] = row[4]

data_list = list(data.values())
```

Instead of appending everything to a list, a dictionary is used to prevent duplicates, and a list is constructed out of its values in the end.

Answer (score 0):

So as to not write your code for you, you need to implement a check as follows :

```py
rows =  [["198.168.1.1", "1.1", "A", "fail", "5"],
           ["198.168.1.1", "1.1", "A", "pass", "10"],
           ["198.168.1.1", "1.1", "B", "fail", "15"],
           ["198.168.1.1", "1.1", "B", "pass", "20"],
           ["198.168.1.2", "1.1", "A", "pass", "25"]]

dict_list = []
data_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    for elem in dict_list:
        if elem['software'] == row[2]:
            print("already exists")

    data_dict['ip'] = row[0]
    data_dict['version'] = row[1]
    data_dict['software'] = row[2]

    dict_list.append(data_dict)
```

And then update the key, val pairs of the dictionary based on if it exists or not.

Comment: This solution is incorrect because you're reusing `data_dict` between loop iterations, and it has O(N^2) complexity because of the inner loop